# how adjust Intellij configuration for new project problem?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, configuration

[screenshot of intellij project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbEgj.png)

i know there's alot of question with my title but i can't find answer

intellij was working fine but i remove the old ubuntu and install new one and then install intellij

so now intellij new projects work also fine but when i open existing project that exists before new ubuntu they doesn't work well and i can't select class as Main class 
and the project structure itself is so strange 
i can't find source and classes and so on

and when new project created it say no idea annotations attached to the jdk intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were the [project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#project-settings) for the old projects preserved in the same place (directory)? If not, open existing projects via File | New | [Project from Existing Sources...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#importing-project) action so that IDE re-creates the project settings and project structure.

If you do not want to delete previous settings and there are issues with project structure - change it manually in File | Project Structure | Modules | `<module name>` by [configuring content roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#configuring-content-roots) for module: e.g. on the image you need to add content with the `StronglyConnected components` root directory and specify `src` folder as a **source root** [by marking it as such](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#project_tool_window).